# How do I get the "Migrate to JUnit 5" option to appear in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit4, junit5

According to [these release notes](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/11/intellij-idea-2017-3-junit-support/) Intellij 2017.3 and later should have a feature that enables easy migration from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5 (a.k.a. JUnit Jupiter).

[image: Migrate to JUnit 5 Intellij IDEA inspection]

However, that's not appearing for me. How do I get it to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not showing up, then the inspection is turned off. You can enable it in the Settings by going to:

Editor → Inspections → Java → JUnit → JUnit 4 test can be JUnit 5

[image: Turning on the "JUnit 4 test can be JUnit 5" inspection in Intellij IDEA]

Also, make sure that JUnit Jupiter is on your classpath.